# Groovy TimeCategory bad millseconds addition

Tags: groovy, milliseconds

When try this sample code:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    800.millisecond + 300.millisecond
}
```

in groovy web [console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/), I get a funny result:

```
0.1100 seconds
```

Does any one know why this happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a bug, the TimeDuration contains 1100 milliseconds, but when it prints it out, it converts it wrongly to seconds.

<s>[I've added it to the Groovy JIRA as a bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5751)</s> **EDIT** ***It's now marked as FIXED for versions 2.0.6, 1.8.9 and 2.1.0***

In the mean time, I guess you'll need to do your own converter from TimeDuration to String :-/

---

#### Edit

You could do something like this (and there is probably a neater way of doing it)

```
groovy.time.TimeDuration.metaClass.normalize = { ->
  def newdmap = ['days','hours','minutes','seconds','millis'].collectEntries { 
    [ (it):delegate."$it" ]
  }.with { dmap ->
    [millis:1000,seconds:60,minutes:60,hours:24,days:-1].inject( [ dur:[ days:0, hours:0, minutes:0, seconds:0, millis:0 ], roll:0 ] ) { val, field ->
      val.dur."$field.key" = dmap."$field.key" + val.roll
      val.roll = val.dur."$field.key".intdiv( field.value )
      val.dur."$field.key" = field.value < 0 ?
                               val.dur."$field.key" :
                               val.dur."$field.key" % field.value
      val
    }.dur
  }
  new TimeDuration( newdmap.days, newdmap.hours, newdmap.minutes, newdmap.seconds, newdmap.millis )
}
```

That adds a `normalize` method to `TimeDuration`, so then doing:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    800.millisecond + 300.millisecond
}.normalize()
```

Shows `1.100 seconds`

I haven't done a huge amount of testing on that method, so be warned it could do with some unit tests to make sure it doesn't fall over with other situations.